# Get React props with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver

I need to find ReactJs props for a test with Selenium Webdriver.

I can't find anything that says I can do it. I thought about using a script, but I'm also unable to find something with js that would get me what I want.

Does anybody know if doing this is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure its possible, but, the react chrome tools let you read props from components so there must be something that can get inside.
That being said, Selenium Webdriver is a browser testing env, you shouldn't be looking at props with it, just results

Comment: I know I shouldn't, but so far there is data that would help me do some stuff there. Another option is to ask for that data to be in the HTML hidden, but for now I would like to avoid that. Thanks